# Github Actions setup-java - read maven packages from a private nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I have a private nexus repository where I need to read internal libraries and also publish.

I am following the guide [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#Publishing-using-Apache-Maven) for publishing using setup-java, but I can't figure out how can I instruct actions to read artifacts from my nexus repository.

```
name: Publish package to Nexus

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Nexus Repository
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'corretto'
          cache: 'maven'
          server-id: nexus-snapshots
          server-username: MAVEN_USERNAME
          server-password: MAVEN_PASSWORD
      - name: Publish package
        run: mvn --batch-mode deploy
        env:
          MAVEN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.NEXUS_PUBLISHER_USERNAME }}
          MAVEN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.NEXUS_PUBLISHER_PASSWORD }}
```

Here's the distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    <url>${NEXUS_SNAPSHOT_URL_OMITTED}</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
  <repository>
    <id>nexus-release</id>
    <url>${NEXUS_RELEASE_URL_OMITTED}</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Ideally, I would use [settings-path](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#apache-maven-with-a-settings-path), but at the moment, my setup is not yet using a self-hosted runner.

EDIT: I can use a different action like [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/maven-settings-action#settingsxml-with-servers-section), but I'm wondering if I can solve this using setup-java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the private repositories you want to use in your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>private-repo</id>
            <url>${URL}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
...
</project>
```

In your GitHub repo you can add a secret `MAVEN_SERVERS`:

```
[{"id": "private-repo", "username": "USERNAME", "password": "PASSWORD"}]
```

And use it in your [GitHub actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/maven-settings-action#settingsxml-with-servers-section):

```
steps:
- uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.8.0
  with:
    servers: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_SERVERS}}
```

Comment: I've seen this action and looking at it as a last resort, I am wondering if I can solve this using setup-java.

Comment: This is the best approach outside of self-hosted runner